# Does every first order theory have a pointwise definable model?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

By Löwenheim–Skolem theorem every first order theory must have a countable model.

> Question: Is there a result stating that every first order theory must have a pointwise definable model? i.e. a model in which every object is definable in a parameter free manner?

If the answer is to the negative then:

> Question: is there a criterion that can characterize all first order theories that defies the above feature?

***EDIT***: although my original intention was about definability in the language of the meta-theory in which the model for the theory in question is constructed, and I take the meta-theory to be ZFC. However, the question is understood along the standard lines to be about definability in the language of the theory in question. And answers had been put forth along that line.

> Question: along the standard notions, what would make a theory defy having a definable pointwise model ? is there a common criterion that all such theories enjoy?

Comment: Take the theory in the language of equality stating there are infinitely many objects in the universe.

Comment: Or DLO in the language of orders.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't get your answer, of course this theory has a pointwise definable model, a pointwise definable model of ZFC would be a model of that theory [in the first comment of yours], the other comment I didn't understand, what is DLO?

Comment: @Zuhair - neither the theory of equality with infinitely many elements, nor the theory of dense linear orders, have pointwise definable models in their original languages.

Comment: but I didn't limit the definable model to be in the original language of the theory, it should be definable in the language of the theory in which the model is constructed, and this need not be the same language of the original theory.

Comment: How can you define anything if your language only had equality?

Comment: you can have a model of this theory in ZFC which has primitives other than equality, when I said definability I meant in the language of the theory in which the pointwise definable model is constructed, not in the language of the interpreted theory

Comment: Every model is pointwise definable in a larger language - simply add a constant symbol for every element of the model.  This allows parameters to be replaced with constants. // In particular, because the Henkin construction creates term models based on a new set of constant symbols, any countable model made with the Henkin construction will be pointwise definable in the extended language of the construction.

Comment: Riffing a bit on Alex's last paragraph: given a countable first-order theory $T$ in a language $\Sigma$ not containing "$\in$," let $M$ be a countable model of $T$. Then we can *expand* $M$ to a $\Sigma\cup\{\in\}$-structure $M^*$ so that $M\upharpoonright\{\in\}$ is a pointwise-definable model of ZFC (simply because there exist pointwise-definable models of ZFC, so just "glue" one to the original $M$); $M^*$ is clearly pointwise definable according to the actual definition (every element of $M^*$ is definable in $M^*$ by a formula in the language of $M^*$). (cont'd)

Comment: This shows that **every countable first-order theory has a model with an expansion which is pointwise definable**. This is a snappier situation than putting a model inside an ambient model of ZFC, so may be more satisfying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the stated question: "Does every (consistent) first-order theory have a pointwise definable model?" is No. Examples were given by Asaf Karagila in the comments, but I'll elaborate a bit.

The easiest example is the theory of an infinite set in the empty language (with just a symbol $=$ for equality). No model of this theory has any element which is definable without parameters. Indeed, any element of a structure $M$ which is definable without parameters is fixed by all automorphisms of $M$. But for any infinite set $A$ and any element $a\in A$, there is an automorphism of $A$ moving $a$.

Another example is the theory DLO of dense linear orders without endpoints in the language $\{\leq\}$. Again, no model has any element which is definable without parameters. Here we can note that if $\varphi(x)$ were a formula defining a unique element in some model, then since DLO is a complete theory, $\varphi(x)$ would define a unique element in every model, in particular in the unique (up to isomorphism) countable model of DLO, $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$. But by Cantor's back-and-forth argument, for any $q,q'\in \mathbb{Q}$, there is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ moving $q$ to $q'$.

---

But in the comments, you specified:

> When I said definability I meant in the language of the theory in which the pointwise definable model is constructed, not in the language of the interpreted theory.

This is an extremely unusual use of language. Readers of your question will naturally assume that "definable" means the standard thing: definable in the language of the first-order theory in question.

It also makes the question pretty vague, since you haven't specified the meta-theory. The answer obviously depends on which theory we're using to "construct models". e.g. if that theory can't prove the completeness theorem for first-order logic, then it can't even prove that an arbitrary consistent theory has *any* models, much less pointwise definable ones.

But OK. Let's assume the meta-theory is ZFC. The argument is so simple that it's easy to see that any natural set theory which is strong enough to prove the completeness theorem and downward Löwenheim-Skolem will work just as well.

---

If a theory $T$ in a countable language is consistent, it has a countable model. So it has a model with domain $\mathbb{N}$. Since every natural number is definable without parameters in ZFC, $T$ has a pointwise definable model in your sense.

Comment: I think the question is useless in its current form, since it uses standard terms in secret, private ways, that no one else does. Alex, would you consider adding a paragraph or two addressing the question anybody other than the poster would understand when reading it, so the question is useful to others and it is worth keeping it around?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Sure, that's a good idea.